# Is it possible to pipe GDB commands?

Tags: gdb

Is there a way in GDB to cascade two commands, like pipes un UNIX ?
I have tried to pipe but it did not work.

If i want to see what is stored at 0xbfffefd4 address, i type:

```
  x/x 0xbfffefd4
```

It gives me 0xbffff1dc in my example

if now i want to see what is stored at 0xbffff1dc, i have to type:

```
  x/x 0xbffff1dc
```

Is there a way to pipe those 2 commands ?

Something like x/x (x/x 0xbfffefd4) ?

By the way, is there a way to show characters instead of hex ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to compose gdb commands in a few ways, but it isn't easy.

In the specific case of indirection, you can just use C operators.  That is:

```
(gdb) x/x *(void**)0xbfffefd4
```

> By the way, is there a way to show characters instead of hex ?

See `help x` -- it says that the `/c` format shows characters.  Another way is to cast a pointer to a `char *`, and gdb will print it as a string:

```
(gdb) print (char *) 0xADDR
```

For more general composition of *commands* (as opposed to *expressions*, which are much simpler to deal with), there are two approaches.  Both are a pain.

The old school method is to use a combination of logging and `shell`.  What you do is use `set logging` and its subcommands to write the output to a file.  Then you use `shell` to rewrite this file into a new gdb script.  Finally, `source` the resulting file to execute the command you wanted.

The new school approach is to write a custom command in Python that does what you want.  You could probably write a generic composition command if that is what you really want.